# Need guide on how to temporary deduct product quantity.

Tags: javascript, php

I just spot an bug on my eCommerce website that Im not sure how to fully fix it. 
I will not provide any code as there isnt anything to be upload that would change the system i built im not asking a review of what is wrong with my code. Im not looking for a code answer, but more an advice of what I should do.

In the process of a customer buying a product from my eCommerce website he/she will be directed to paypal, once paypal is proceed, my database will save his information as well as deduct the quantity of items purchased from the database(the deduction is to stop future customer buying an out of stuck item).

A problem that happened few days back is, once customer press "pay now" button information is sent to paypal and no information is returned until payment is completed. Meaning if an item with 1 quantity is left on the database before a customer pressed "buy now" button, there will still be 1 item left until that transaction is completed leaving a gab of minutes where another customer could also go to the same item and press "buy now". This means two customer could ended up purchasing an item with only 1 in stock.

How could I go about to fix this? Should I add a temporary deduction of the stock if someone pressed "pay now" button? How does website normally deal with this?

Thanks

Cant wait for the down votes, but hope someone is nice enough to give me some light!

Comment: Ah the joys of asynchronous programming. You could "lock" the item when the checkout process is started, and then timeout if it's not completed within a certain time period?

Comment: Thats what I been thinking to do, just dont know any methods name so its hard looking for an example. when you dont know what you are looking for :(

Comment: AS @evolutionxbox mentioned, you could have a temporary storage (SQL table or the like) that temporarily holds all "active carts" for the time being. Then whenever you poll your available products, you'd have to subtract those that are in carts. I would create an expiration on the lock, like a lot of ticket sales that say "you have 15 minutes to complete this transaction..." so that if they leave the page, it gets put back into the pool.

Comment: @kchason Thanks yeah that sounds what I need. What im finding hard to understand is. Where do i right this code? would it be SQL? server side client side? what im finding difficult is finding the right method to do it. if I write a php script that does what you suggested. BUT what if the customer add the items to chart and then closes the browser? I cant alter that temporary table then.

Comment: I would use a regular (non-temporary) table, and just add the entries to it. You can look at beforeunload events in Javascript, but that's not going to be perfect, hence why you'd want a time out.

Comment: @kchason  "so that if they leave the page, it gets put back into the pool." how do I run a script if they leave the page? i cant get around it

Comment: You don't, you just set an expiration, so that either a cron script cleans it up, or it gets ignored from the count